# Простой пример вызова C++ функции из QML в Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qml

Хоть убейте не могу понять... Все примеры для Qt4.
Дайте, пжл, простой пример вызова функции C++ из QML и обратный, т.е. из C++ функцию QML. 
Еще вопрос: как обращаться к компонентам QML из C++, скажем, для изменения цвета, размера и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет практически никакой разницы между Qt4 и Qt5, в этом плане, всё то же самое.
[Здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) всё расписано, правда на английском. Но примеры кода говорят сами за себя. Если это не поможет, то показывайте пример кода, который у Вас не работает - будем разбираться.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще такой вопрос: как вызвать процедуру при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Т.е. у меня есть main.qml (тут функция) в ней подгружается MainForm.ui.qml: MainForm {anchors.fill: parent }. Если я пишу для кнопки (она находится в MainForm) onClicked: qmlFunction(), то выдает ошибку "Функция не поддерживается в Qt Quick UI". Как быть?

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался сам.